# What is similar to Azure "Resource Group" in Oracle Cloud infrastructure?

Tags: azure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm fairly new to OCI.
What is a similar or close concept in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure similar to Microsoft Azure "Resource Groups"?

In Azure when a resource group is deleted all resources in that group will also be deleted along with it. But "Compartments" in Oracle cloud infrastructure is not the exact same concept, because in order to delete a compartment, each resource should be deleted first and then the compartment should be deleted. Is it possible to delete a compartment along with its resources without deleting resources one by one?

Answer (score 4):

I see two options here:

- You may use instance pools. [Deleting an instance pool](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/deletinginstancepool.htm) will delete all
  of its resources, but that only includes instances, boot volumes and
  block volumes. Networking and other resources wouldn't be impacted. Instance Pool only works for compute instances having the same configuration, so this is not a generic solution for your question.
- [Resource Manager](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/ResourceManager/Concepts/resourcemanager.htm) can be used to create a stack with all the resources
  you need. When you destroy a stack by launching a destroy job, it will delete all the resources that are part of the stack. But resource manager requires you to
  create Terraform config files, which can be applied through the OCI
  Console. This also means that you cannot create any components of the stack
  manually using the GUI, you have to keep using the Resource Manager even if you would like to update any resources of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Compartments in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure is similar to Azure Resource groups.

As per the [doc](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingcompartments.htm#delcomp), It is not possible to delete all the resources in compartment at a time similar to Azure.